# Как передать сумму доставки в data-price у кнопки input?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть кнопка

```
<input type="email" id="email" required name="email" class="text-input" data-price-for-one="0" data-price="0">
```

и плагин Boxberry, в котором при выборе пункта выдачи определяется сумма доставки:

```
document.getElementById('js-pricedelivery').innerHTML = result.price;
```

[image: скрин]
Вопрос: как передать эту стоимость в "data-price"?

Answer (score 0):

Значение `data-bubu` можно поменять через свойство `element.dataset.bubu` 

P.s. сделаем вид, что у вас там хитрый код и невозможно вместо innerText прямо записать и тут, и там `= result.price;`

```js
let delivery = document.getElementById('js-pricedelivery');

let rad = document.querySelectorAll('.rad'); 

for( let i = 0; i < rad.length; i++ ) {
  rad[i].addEventListener('change', function(){

    for( let u = 0; u < rad.length; u++ ){ rad[u].dataset.price = 0; }

    this.dataset.price = delivery.innerText;
    
    //Ненужное демо
    demo.innerText = `Теперь у радио номер ${(i+1)} data-price="${delivery.innerText}", а у остальных - 0`
  });
}
```

```css
.flaticon-check {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #cc006c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px; text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.flaticon-check:hover {
  background-color: #fee;
}

.rad { display: none; }

.rad:checked + .flaticon-check::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px; height: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: -7px; right: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}
.rad:checked + .flaticon-check::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px; height: 18px;
  background-color: #dd0033;
  top: -8px; right: -4px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input class="rad" id="radio45" type="radio" name="radio3" data-price-for-one="0" data-price="0">
<label class="flaticon-check" for="radio45">В пункт самовывоза</label>

<input class="rad" id="radio46" type="radio" name="radio3" data-price-for-one="0" data-price="0">
<label class="flaticon-check" for="radio46">До метро</label>

<input class="rad" id="radio47" type="radio" name="radio3" data-price-for-one="0" data-price="0">
<label class="flaticon-check" for="radio47">До адреса</label>

<p>Стоимость доставки: <span id="js-pricedelivery"><b>153</b></span></p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: "data-price-for-one" уже итак знает, как суммироваться с остальными значениями, поэтому сложность именно в присвоении стоимости из "js-pricedelivery". Я кнопку не ту прислала:

Comment: <input type="radio" id="radio45" name="radio3" data-price-for-one="0" data-price="0"> <label class="flaticon-check" for="radio45">Доставка в пункт самовывоза</label>

Comment: Что-то я не пойму логику) В скрипт не вникал... У первого показывает предыдущее, у остальных - нет. Не наоборот должно быть?

Comment: @InDevX только при первом клике на первую кнопку (когда изначально "предыдущее" совпадает с кликнутой), дальше предыдущее обнуляется по кругу... Аффтару вроде не принципиален этот момент)

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME к вопросу сейчас добавила скрин. попробовала ваш способ, не передается сумма в итого. Под "Выбрать ПВЗ" пишется стоимость доставки, которую надо передать в "Итог". Передается она так: Стоимость доставки <b class="result" id="js-pricedelivery"></b> Для передачи в предыдущих шагах формах используется data-price-for-one.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME нет, 1650 - это получилась такая сумма при выбранных опциях на других шагах. нас интересует стоимость 153, которая указана на скрине под кнопкой "Выбрать ПВЗ". Вот это число надо присвоить data-price и оно прибавит 153 к 1650 рублям. надеюсь понятно объяснила

Comment: @Ольга обновлено*